# Is there any way for a System.Data.Entity.Database to create itself without using pre-created scripts?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, sql-server, entity-framework

I'm trying to create an automated database deployment system where only the `DbConext` is checked into source control a database with the corresponding schema is created and then the live database in the environment is synced from it. I started out with

```
using(var context = new MyDbContext("ScriptDb")
{
    context.Database.Create();
    Sync("ScriptDb", "LiveDb"); // not implemented yet
}
```

but I see that `Create()` just runs my migration scripts that were created. So if I make a change to `MyDbContext` without running `Add-Migration` from the nuget command line it, it does not show up in `ScriptDb`.

I'm wondering if there is a way to do `Create()` without migration scripts. Because the problem I'm having with migration scripts in source control is that if a there's a script like `DoSomeUpdate_8738913.cs` that contains a line like

`context.SomeEntites.Insert(new SomeEntity() { SomeValue = SomeEnum.SomeValue })`

then if I want to make `SomeEnum.SomeValue` obsolete from my code base, I can't because it needs to be part of the migration history. Does my problem make sense?

Comment: Do you use Seed(MyDbContext context) in your migration config class? Can you post the migration in which Insert() is called? Have you edited the migration manually?